# Grails Spring Security and Ajax

Tags: ajax, grails, spring-security

I'm working on a Grails application and am displaying login and signup form on same page. When user is trying to signup I would like to send Ajax request to check if his username is unique in database. When I do that I constantly get this error:

```
http://localhost:8080/Testapp/login/authAjax 401 (Unauthorized)
```

Here is JS for ajax call:

```
function checkUsernameInDatabase() {

var usernameElement =  document.getElementById("username_signup");

$.post( "${createLink(controller:'main',action:'checkDatabaseUsername')}", { usernameVal: usernameElement.value})
   .done(function( data ) {
      console.log("username return " + data);
   });
}
```

Here is Grails function that should handle the request:

```
@Secured(['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'])
boolean checkDatabaseUsername() {
   return true; 
}
```

I also added this in config.groovy

```
'/checkDatabaseUsername': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY']
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is login controller being called when I'm not trying to log in?

Comment: Are you sure your conroller action is mapped to `/checkDatabaseUsername`? Typically the format is `controlerName/action`, unless you have setup your own mapping in `URLMappings.groovy`. If so, include that in your question as well.

Comment: Independent of the security issue, you shouldn't be returning boolean from a controller method. Render JSON containing a boolean that you access from the client. One example would be `render([result: true] as JSON)`. The only thing you should ever return from a controller action is a model map to be rendered by convention with the GSP that corresponds to the method name.

Comment: @Joshua Moore
i tryed with controlerName/action i still got the same error

@ Burt Beckwith
i cannot access any method with ajax call, i tryed with render as well

Comment: Can you please paste other spring related config from Config.groovy?

Comment: // Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.pozicije.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.pozicije.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.pozicije.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
 '/':                              ['permitAll'],
 '/index':                         ['permitAll'],
 '/index.gsp':                     ['permitAll'],
 '/assets/**':                     ['permitAll'],

Comment: '/**/images/**':                  ['permitAll'],
 '/**/favicon.ico':                ['permitAll'],
 '/dbconsole/**':                  ['permitAll'],
 '/simpleCaptcha/**':              ['permitAll']
]
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = '/main/createposition'

Comment: grails.plugin.springsecurity.failureHandler.defaultFailureUrl = '/main/signup?login_fail=1'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.failureHandler.ajaxAuthFailUrl = '/main/signup?login_fail=1'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.postOnly = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.afterLogoutUrl = '/main/index'